# How to use Python subprocess module to read data from the Linux terminal

Tags: python, linux

This is my code so far:

```
import subprocess


def __init__(pingcount, hostname):

    try:
        out, error = subprocess.Popen.communicate(subprocess.Popen("ping -n " +  pingcount + ' ' + hostname), timeout=10)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        subprocess.Popen.kill(subprocess.Popen)
        return "No connection to terminal. Contact system administrator."

    print(str(out))

    if str(out).find("rtt") != -1:
        return str(out)[str(out).find("rtt"):]
    else:
        return "No connection to server."
```

Similar code works on Windows, but upon calling this function, I get a return value of `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PING(8) man page in Linux:

> **-c** count Stop  after sending count ECHO_REQUEST packets. With deadline option, ping waits for count ECHO_REPLY packets, until the timeout expires.
>
> **-n** Numeric output only. No attempt will be made to lookup symbolic names for host addresses.

You're passing `-n` argument as a result the command fails in Linux:

```
$ ping -n 10 www.google.com
connect: Invalid argument
```

---

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, TimeoutExpired
import sys 

# inside class body
def __init__(pingcount, hostname):
    if sys.platform == "linux": 
        cmd = ["ping", "-c", pingcount,  hostname]
    else: 
        cmd = "ping -n " +  pingcount + ' ' + hostname     # else: assume Windows 
    
    proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    
    try:
        proc_stdout, proc_stderr = proc.communicate(timeout=19)
    except TimeoutExpired:
        proc.kill()             # on Linux send SIGKILL signal
        return "No connection to terminal. Contact system administrator."
    
    # rest of code...
```

The `if` statement at the beginning simply checks the operating system on which Python is running to determined the right command to pass to `Popen`.

Note: using `proc.kill` send SIGTERM on POSIX operating systems like Linux. This is a very brutal way to kill the process. The operating system will forcibly terminate the process and remove it from memory. Probably you need to use `proce.terminate` instead. However, I don't see serious implications here for using `proc.kill` with `ping`. see [`Popen.kill`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) section in the documentation of the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed the incorrect arguments. Also, I've been executing the wrong file over SSH. I must need more coffee. Cheers!